# How to convert a row into two columns fixing certain columns?

Tags: sql, sas

Suppose the following observation in a table:

```
Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Var5   Var6
 a      b      c      d      e      f
```

Now, I want to have two rows, which differ in Var3/Var4 and in Var5/Var5, respectively. That is:

```
Var1   Var2   VarX   VarY
 a      b      c      d
 a      b      e      f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union all`:

```
select var1, var2, var3 as varx, var4 as vary
from t
union all
select var1, var2, var5, var6
from t;
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Thank you very much for your quick answer. This seems to be obvious. However, I couldn't find it when googling it.  Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickBalada . . . Dealing with data is tricky.  Sas and SQL both have lots of ways of doing things . . . it can be hard to figure out the right approach.